# How can I programmatically trigger "Reset Column Layout" event on a winforms datagrid?

Tags: winforms, datagrid

When releasing the latest iteration of our winforms application there is often confusion when users cannot see changes developers have made to a particular datagrid. Perhaps we've added,  resized or re-ordered columns on purpose and we'd like users to benefit from the change. Because their local settings cache the grid layouts they must explicitly right-click and select "Reset Column Layout" to clear that cache and see the latest changes.

What I really need is a way of programmatically trigger "Reset Column Layout" command on grids that have changed in the latest iteration. It should probably only happen once, the first time they run the new build.

Answer (score 0):

You could somehow have your installer remove the grid layout piece of the local settings. That way you'd make sure the layout would be reset and that it would only happen once.